# Programmatic way of modifying cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra

We are creating a cassandra cluster at runtime and information like "cluster-name" and IP addresses of "seeds" are available only at runtime. Is there a java wrapper for cassandra.yaml that allows setters and getters for cassandra.yaml and saves it to disk? I understand that I can always create a wrapper myself but wanted to know if theres already one available.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a java wrapper for cassandra.yaml that allows setters and getters for cassandra.yaml and saves it to disk?

Not that I am aware of.  Although, that's a good idea for an OpenSource project!

I have done this a few different ways in the past.  One is with a combination of Chef and [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template).  Essentially, your cassandra.yaml contains variable place-holders, which are filled by a combination of default attributes (Chef) and cluster-specific settings (consul-template) when your deployment recipe runs.

I have also done this with a Bash script using `sed` (for a couple of our non-Chef environments).  This is an excerpt from a script I wrote to migrate a DataStax Enterprise installation to an Apache Cassandra (open source) install:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml /etc/cassandra/conf

#set GossipingPropertyFileSnitch in cassandra.yaml
sed -i 's/endpoint_snitch: com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch/endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch/' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml

#set truststore location
sed -i 's/truststore: \/etc\/dse\/cassandra\//truststore: \/etc\/cassandra\/conf\//g' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml

#set keystore location
sed -i 's/keystore: \/etc\/dse\/cassandra\//keystore: \/etc\/cassandra\/conf\//g' /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

Essentially here, you're doing a regex-replace for specific yaml property settings.  Specifically, I needed to update the snitch, and the locations of the keystore/truststore.  It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, thats close to how I am doing it today. I have created a dummy cassandra.yaml with placeholders like __TRUST_STORE__ and then at runtime we replace these placeholders with real values. Its just that it looks ugly and is prone to errors. I like your idea of creating an open source java project for this. I'll do it if there isn't one.